# How to stop array results from being merged when they share the same array key?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an issue trying to build an array where the status ID is the key and ALL posts related to the statuses are sub-arrays relating to the key (status ID).

Here's the (*incorrect*) array I am getting with both array_merge_recursive and manually adding items to the array (array 1):

```
Array
(
    [res_1] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => NEEDS REVIEW
            [status_color] => 666666
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Add feature that allows our team to add internal notes on ideas
                    [post_description] => Sometimes our team needs to leave feedback that users should not see publicly. Having this feature would allow the team to collaborate better at scale.
                    [categories] => Admin,Communication
                )

        )

    [res_2] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => PLANNED
            [status_color] => aa5c9e
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Add support for multiple languages
                    [post_description] => We have customers across the globe who would appreciate this page to be localized to their language
                    [categories] => Integrations
                )

        )

    [res_3] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => IN PROGRESS
            [status_color] => 3333cc
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Allow users to add an image with their feature request
                    [post_description] => Sometimes users want something visual, having an example really helps.
                    [categories] => Uncategorized
                )

        )

    [res_4] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => COMPLETED
            [status_color] => 7ac01d
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Add feature that allows @mentioning in comments
                    [post_description] => There is no hierarchy in comments so it's hard to reply to one specific user if there is a longer thread of comments.
                    [categories] => Communication
                )

        )

)
```

Here's something like what I am expecting to happen (every status ID is an array with multiple posts as sub-arrays):

```
Array
(
    [res_1] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => NEEDS REVIEW
            [status_color] => 666666
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Add feature that allows our team to add internal notes on ideas
                    [post_description] => Sometimes our team needs to leave feedback that users should not see publicly. Having this feature would allow the team to collaborate better at scale.
                    [categories] => Admin,Communication
                )

        )

    [res_2] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => PLANNED
            [status_color] => aa5c9e
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Add support for multiple languages
                    [post_description] => We have customers across the globe who would appreciate this page to be localized to their language
                    [categories] => Integrations
                )

        )

    [res_3] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => IN PROGRESS
            [status_color] => 3333cc
            [post] => Array
                (
                    [post_title] => Allow users to add an image with their feature request
                    [post_description] => Sometimes users want something visual, having an example really helps.
                    [categories] => Uncategorized
                )

        )

    [res_4] => Array
        (
            [status_name] => COMPLETED
            [status_color] => 7ac01d
            [post] => Array(       
                    [0] => Array (
                          [post_title] => Add feature that allows @mentioning in comments
                          [post_description] => There is no hierarchy in comments so its hard to reply to one specific user if there is a longer thread of comments.
                          [categories] => Communication
                          )
                   [1] => Array (
                         [post_title] => Feature Number 5
                         [post_description] => lorum ipsum awesomeness.
                         [categories] => Admin
                         )
              )
)
```

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. Running two separate DB queries: one to fetch statuses and another to fetch posts then merging the arrays recursively and changing the array keys to a string. This does the same thing, post 5 never shows up in the newly merged array.
2. Same as above - ran two separate queries and rebuilt the array manually, the same result the 5th post never appears.
3. I printed out the database result from `$stmt2->fetchAll();` all 5 posts are there in the result-set directly from the database. The 5th one just won't persist when merging arrays or building a fresh one so the posts can relate to the statuses.
4. I also tried joining the tables with SQL but even grouping by resolution_id does the same thing, post number 5 gets lost by the grouping. I've tried sub-queries too.

DB Results array for just posts:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Feature number 5
            [0] => Feature number 5
            [description] => lorum ipsum awesomeness
            [1] => lorum ipsum awesomeness
            [resolution_id] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [category_names] => Admin
            [3] => Admin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Allow users to add an image with their feature request
            [0] => Allow users to add an image with their feature request
            [description] => Sometimes users want something visual, having an example really helps.
            [1] => Sometimes users want something visual, having an example really helps.
            [resolution_id] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [category_names] => Uncategorized
            [3] => Uncategorized
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Add support for multiple languages
            [0] => Add support for multiple languages
            [description] => We have customers across the globe who would appreciate this page to be localized to their language
            [1] => We have customers across the globe who would appreciate this page to be localized to their language
            [resolution_id] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [category_names] => Integrations
            [3] => Integrations
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Add feature that allows @mentioning in comments
            [0] => Add feature that allows @mentioning in comments
            [description] => There is no hierarchy in comments so it's hard to reply to one specific user if there is a longer thread of comments.
            [1] => There is no hierarchy in comments so it's hard to reply to one specific user if there is a longer thread of comments.
            [resolution_id] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [category_names] => Communication
            [3] => Communication
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Add feature that allows our team to add internal notes on ideas
            [0] => Add feature that allows our team to add internal notes on ideas
            [description] => Sometimes our team needs to leave feedback that users should not see publicly. Having this feature would allow the team to collaborate better at scale.
            [1] => Sometimes our team needs to leave feedback that users should not see publicly. Having this feature would allow the team to collaborate better at scale.
            [resolution_id] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [category_names] => Admin,Communication
            [3] => Admin,Communication
        )

)
```

Since the data is always going to be dynamic (users can choose status names and create as many as they need to) I can't just hard-code the status names/ids and run 4 queries to populate the columns.

To prevent this from being an essay long post, here are the bits of code that are building the array from array 1:

Builds the initial statuses array from the query results from the resolutions table.

```
 $statuses = [];

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $statuses['res_' . $row['id']] = ['status_name' => $row['name'], 'status_color' => $row['color']];
    }
```

Adds the individual posts to the statuses array:

```
 foreach ($dbposts as $row2) {
            $statuses['res_' . $row2['resolution_id']]['post'] = ['post_title' => $row2['title'], 'post_description' => $row2['description'], 'categories' => $row2['category_names']];
        }
```

The resolution ID is concatenated with res_ from when I tried doing an array merge based on keys. It would not merge when the keys were just integers.

Finally some context behind why I am trying to do what I am trying to do. I am building a platform where companies can have users submit feature requests and view the results in a list view or board view. The list view was a piece of cake since the board view needs to be per status, this is where I am having trouble. I hard-coded the board view values to demonstrate the expected end-result:

[image]

Not looking for someone to write my code for me, just looking for some guidance - perhaps I am building or merging the arrays wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the array of posts, you need to *append* elements to the array of posts. Currently, you are just *assigning* a single element to the array over and over, which overwrites the previous value of the entire array.

The code to append posts:

```
$statuses['res_' . $row2['resolution_id']]['post'][] = ['post_title' => $row2['title'], 'post_description' => $row2['description'], 'categories' => $row2['category_names']];
```

Note the `[]` which I added to the end of the left side of the assignment operator.